# Snowflake Replication across regions : Will increasing the warehouse size on either end make a difference in speed?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a snowflake instance in two regions. Both warehouses are size small.
When replicating the database from one snowflake instance to another, would changing the warehouse size to a larger size on the:
1 Source warehouse
2 Destination warehouse
3 Both warehouses

Make a significant difference or is the traffic the major time cost?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Customers do not control the warehouse used for replication.  Snowflake-provided warehouse is used.